# excel 2010 dashboard error : This pivottable report is invalid. Try refreshing the data

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, excel-2010, pivot-table, ssas-2012

Hi after we upgraded SQl server from 2008R2 to 2012, all the company wide production excel 2010 dashboards-excel slicers, pivot tables (which where built on SQL 2008R2) which now connect to SSAS 2012 cubes are giving following error for all the users...

"This pivottable report is invalid. Try refreshing the data."

I have observed that the connection string in the excel is:

Provider=**MSOLAP.4**;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=ABCD;Data Source=prodolap.com;MDX Compatibility=1;Safety Options=2;MDX Missing Member Mode=Error

so I installed the SQL server 2012 **ADOMD drivers** and I changed the connection string from **MSOLAP.4 to MSOLAP.5** as it is specific to SQl 2012 but it did not fix the issue.

The excel version is 2010 , 32 bit version.

Are there any specific drivers that I need to install or anything.

Any suggestions to resolve the problem are surely appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see an issue with your connection string.  Are you sure your server name and SSAS db are correct?

Comment: Yes they are, when you opne the file it gets the correct data and after that when you try to filter data it gives out refresh error, but the next time when you click on the same filters the data refresh just fine the second time.